# Circular data entry in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, rethinkdb

I am new to mongoDB and am interested in the geospatial data feature.

I know that it's possible to create data points and then use circular queries to see if the point is inside.

I don't want to do this though. I want to experiment by making a little game where the user has a 1-d point position on the earth and there are circular (2-d) data entries that are like explosion radius' or infection radius'. Then I want to be able to compute which explosions/infections (2-d) the user (1-d point) is being affected by.

Sorry if this sounds crazy. Let me know if this is even possible. I have seen that rethinkdb can do something like it, but I was hoping mongodb would too.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [introduction](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [MongoDB docs on geospatial queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) and elaborate your question, if still necessary. Otherwise, you can remove it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I was unclear. I read the geospatial documentation for MongoDB, and I am unsure if it is possible to make circular, two-dimensional documents. i would like to know in which two-dimensional areas that a user using GPS is contained in. The documentation speaks of circular queries, but I can only find documentation on circular documents (data entries) for rethinkDB

Comment: You have a position. Now an explosion happens on a mother position with a radius. All you have to do is to do a query which check for all positions which are in said explosion radius. And to make a circular entry... You need a point and radius...